# How to map Javadoc comments from previous version onto new version?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have the Javadoc .html files generated from an old version of a Java project, and I want to update the new version of the project by merging these Javadoc comments with the new project files, which are uncommented. For instance, I want to take the Javadoc comments for Class A in the old version and insert these comments into the corresponding positions in the new version of Class A.

Is this possible, or do I have to manually copy the comments from each class of the old version into the new version?

Comment: So you're saying that someone rewrote the project from scratch?  (Including not porting the javadoc comment blocks?)

Comment: Not exactly. I got the new version by decompiling a jar file (the only access I have to the new version), which doesn't preserve comments.

Comment: Hmmm, this isn't exactly a standard workflow ;)  I suppose you could write a script to iterate over the HTML files and munge them, but I doubt there's any standard tooling to help you with this.

Comment: @istewart Just a heads up, be careful with decompiling, information is lost when compiling from source to bytecode which will not be present in your decompiled source.

Comment: @ffk By "information" do you mean more than just the comments? This is my first time working with decompiled classes so I'm not completely sure what I'm doing.

Comment: That's correct, the most relevant is all generic types. e.g. List<Foo> becomes List<Object> on compile. There are also optimizations such as inlined constants that will make it more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thanks! I actually haven't noticed any errors with generic types; just based on my spot-checking, it looks like all fields within the classes retained the generic types. But it's a good point to keep in mind.